# How to resolve this compilation error "Using unassigned local variable 'hak'" when using goto?

Tags: c#, compilation, variable-assignment, goto, unassigned-variable

I'm trying below code. It gives me a warning "Use of unassigned local variable 'hak' ". I guess I'm missing something here.

I want it to display "*3 defa yanlış giriş yaptınız. Müşteri hizmetleri temsilcisiyle görüşünüz. İyi günler dileriz.*" when local variable "hak" equals to "0". But it always display "*Hatalı Giriş Yaptınız. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz. **2 hakkınız kalmıştır.***"

```
                   Console.Write("Seçmek istediğiniz 'Kullanıcı Adı'nı belirtiniz: ");
        string kullanici_adi = Console.ReadLine();
        FARKLISIFRE:
        Console.Write("Lütfen Şifrenizi giriniz: ");
        string sifre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Girmiş olduğunuz şifreyi tekrar giriniz: ");
        string sifre2 = Console.ReadLine();

        int karsilastirma = String.Compare(sifre, sifre2);
        if (karsilastirma==0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tebrikler! Kaydınız başarılı bir şekilde oluşturulmuştur.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Girmiş olduğunuz şifreler birbirinden farklıdır. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.");
            goto FARKLISIFRE;
        }

        Console.Write("Giriş yapmak için lütfen '1' seçeneğini giriniz: ");
        char komut = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
        if (komut=='1')
        {
            goto GIRIS;
        }

        else
        {
            Console.Write("Çıkış yaptınız. İyi günler dileriz.");
            goto END;
        }
        
        int hak = 3;

        GIRIS:
        Console.Write("Lütfen Kullanıcı Adınızı Giriniz: ");
        string kullanici_adi_giris = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Lütfen belirlemiş olduğunuz Şifrenizi giriniz: ");
        string sifre_giris = Console.ReadLine();

        int karsilastirma_k_adi = String.Compare(kullanici_adi, kullanici_adi_giris);
        int karsilastirma_sifre = String.Compare(sifre, sifre_giris);
        
        if (karsilastirma_k_adi == 0 && karsilastirma_sifre == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Başarıyla Giriş Yaptınız. Hoşgeldiniz.");
        }
        else if (hak == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("3 defa yanlış giriş yaptınız. Müşteri hizmetleri temsilcisiyle görüşünüz. İyi günler dileriz.");
        }
        else
        {
            hak--;
            Console.WriteLine("Hatalı Giriş Yaptınız. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz. {0} hakkınız kalmıştır.", hak);
            goto GIRIS;
        }
        
        END:
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: CS0165 is the Error Code.

Comment: I don't think the problem starts from here on. `hak` is initialized with an assignment starting here. I think you have another piece of code causing this warning.

Comment: I posted the full code.

Comment: I want it to display "3 defa yanlış giriş yaptınız. Müşteri hizmetleri temsilcisiyle görüşünüz. İyi günler dileriz." when local variable "hak" equals to "0". But it always display "Hatalı Giriş Yaptınız. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz. 2 hakkınız kalmıştır."

Comment: "else if (hak == 0)"  line causes the error code.

Comment: I will consider your advice on using refactoring. But i want to understand this error.

Comment: As you said, when i write "GIRIS: int hak = 3;", this time it always displays "Hatalı Giriş Yaptınız. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz. 2 hakkınız kalmıştır." and there is no decrease.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I figured out what you mean. I solved the problem.

Comment: @Olivier Rogier And thank you also for your advice on "goto".

Comment: Hi @SelçukÖzübek and welcome.  It is considered polite to mark the answer that solved your problem as the answer that solved it. Normally you should see a ✔ left to the every answer. Clicking that ✔ will mark the answer as the one that solved your problem and will mark this answer as solved.

Comment: @KenBonny; i clicked that button yesterday, but it was not accepted.

Comment: @KenBonny; and i also can't vote.

Comment: It's not the up arrow. It looks like a check: ✔. I'm not sure if you need a certain amount of reputation to be able to vote. Since you are new, I thought I'd let you know. It kind of bugs me that there are numerous questions with valid answers that do not have the answered validation. Don't worry too much about it, it's one of my pet peeves. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got this compile error because this line is never executed:

```
int hak = 3;
```

It is because of the GOTOs, the position of the LABELS and the test condition `if...else` above this line: you never pass this line.

To solve this compile error as well as the design problem which is thus generated, you need to refactor all that to remove all the GOTOs.

Indeed, when compiling, before talking about executing, the `if ( komut == '1' ) ... else ...`, the `hak` creation in never reached, going to `GIRIS` or `END`.

Thus after when you try to use `hak`, it never was assigned and the compiler know that and tell you that.

Just to get to compile, you need to write:

```
GIRIS:
int hak = 3;
```

But using GOTOs is trashy and not clean, a very bad [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), as well as being source of mistakes and weird behaviors.

[image]

Avoid goto more than one once per century, and use [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) instead, please.

[GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

[Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

**Example of a minimal solution using a local method**

```
if ( komut == '1' )
{
  int hak = 3;
  GIRIS(ref hak);
}
else
{
  Console.Write("Çıkış yaptınız. İyi günler dileriz.");
}

Console.ReadKey();

void GIRIS(ref int hak)
{
  Console.Write("Lütfen Kullanıcı Adınızı Giriniz: ");
  string kullanici_adi_giris = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.Write("Lütfen belirlemiş olduğunuz Şifrenizi giriniz: ");
  string sifre_giris = Console.ReadLine();

  int karsilastirma_k_adi = String.Compare(kullanici_adi, kullanici_adi_giris);
  int karsilastirma_sifre = String.Compare(sifre, sifre_giris);

  if ( karsilastirma_k_adi == 0 && karsilastirma_sifre == 0 )
  {
    Console.Write("Başarıyla Giriş Yaptınız. Hoşgeldiniz.");
  }
  else if ( hak == 0 )
  {
    Console.Write("3 defa yanlış giriş yaptınız. Müşteri hizmetleri temsilcisiyle görüşünüz. İyi günler dileriz.");
  }
  else
  {
    hak--;
    Console.WriteLine("Hatalı Giriş Yaptınız. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz. {0} hakkınız kalmıştır.", hak);
    GIRIS(ref hak);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @SelçukÖzübek I updated the answer to add a simple but not really advanced nor completely clean refactoring just for this part of the method. You should do the same for the previous LABELs and GOTOs.

Comment: That's very kind of you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is seeing that the line of code that will define a value for the variable `hak` is *before* the label GIRIS. It cannot be guaranteed that the line will be executed, because GIRIS could be reached by the line of code `goto GIRIS`.

Try changing this:

```
int hak = 3;
GIRIS:
```

to this:

```
GIRIS:
int hak = 3;
```

Comment: If this helped you, could you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is missing.  You can take a glance at the @OlivierRogier's solution.

Comment: Yes, wow. He wrote a lot more code to speed you on your way.