# How to refactor these switch cases to handle user choice in natural language?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, refactoring, user-input, multiple-choice

I'm writing several nested switch statements with quite a few cases in some spots.

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a list of cases to then be referenced in later switch statements.

Is there a way to do this?

It would certainly clean up my code.

For example, I have four separate cases for a "yes" answer.

I am looking for a way to store these four cases in a variable and call on that variable each time I want to use them in a switch.

```
Console.Write("\nWere you feeling exhausted? ");
response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
Console.Clear();
switch (response)
{
    case "yes":
    case "y":
    case "yep":
    case "yeah":
        {
            goto ThreeTwo;
        }
    case "no":
    case "n":
    case "nope":
    case "nah":
```

Comment: Please provide sample code.

Comment: Do you mean like an enum? You could use an enum for this.

Comment: This is too vague for concrete answers - can you be more specific? Show some sample code!

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated!

Comment: So the first thing you're going to want to do is to rewrite your code so it's not using `goto`.

Comment: You could create a HashSet with possible "yes" answers, or create a method that takes a string and returns true for "yes" or false otherwise, or a Regular Expression or probably many other ways

Comment: Create a conversion method to convert all of these cases to either a `string` or an `enum` value. Switch on the result of that conversion.

Answer (score 4):

A nice clean way to do this is first to declare an `enum` to represent the answer values. It will need "Yes", "No" *and* "Undefined" (the latter to represent an answer which is neither "Yes" nor "No"):

```
public enum YesOrNo
{
    Undefined,
    Yes,
    No
}
```

Then you can wrap the yes/no detection logic in a class. There are many ways to do this; here's a simple one (you could use a dictionary instead, but for such a small number of strings it's not really necessary, and I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible):

```
public static class YesOrNoDetector
{
    static readonly string[] _yesAnswers = { "yes", "y", "yep", "yeah", "affirmative" };
    static readonly string[] _noAnswers  = { "no",  "n", "nah", "nope", "negative"    };

    public static YesOrNo Detect(string answer)
    {
        if (_yesAnswers.Contains(answer.ToLower()))
            return YesOrNo.Yes;

        if (_noAnswers.Contains(answer.ToLower()))
            return YesOrNo.No;

        return YesOrNo.Undefined;
    }
}
```

(Note how it also handles uppercase answers by converting the string to lowercase before comparing.)

Then your original code becomes something like:

```
switch (YesOrNoDetector.Detect(response))
{
    case YesOrNo.Yes:
    {
        goto ThreeTwo;  // Please get rid of this goto!
    }

    case YesOrNo.No:
    {
        // Handle "No".
        break;
    }

    case YesOrNo.Undefined:
    {
        // Handle incorrect answer.
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, and; even makes use of the switch :-)

Comment: Beat me as well, by about five seconds! Maybe StackOverflow needs some kind of "I'm working on an answer" button.

Comment: Yeah, happens to all of us. :)  Sometimes I think it encourages quick and sloppy answers that the answerer edits after posting, which isn't really ideal - but I've never been able to think of a good solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it worked perfectly! And now I have to ask: why are goto's so universally hated and what would be a good alternative for them. Thanks again! :^)

Comment: @labmate Sometimes a `goto` can be useful, but often they can make the code harder to follow and more error-prone. There's [some discussion about the topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful#:~:text=Every%20control%20structure%20can%20be%20implemented%20in%20terms,and%20these%20have%20been%20eliminated%20by%20structured%20programming.) that you might find interesting. In your case, you might want to put the code in a method and call it, but it's hard to say without context.

Comment: Really nice answer :-) Really wanted to give +100 for **// Please get rid of this goto!** :-)

Answer (score 2):

Having this enum:

```
public enum Answers
{
  Other,
  Yes,
  No
}
```

Any expected possibility can be added.

Also several enums can be created for various use cases.

Here `Other` means not defined, not predicted, unknown, etc.

We can define this allotment/distribution/dispatch table:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

readonly Dictionary<Answers, List<string>> AcceptedAnswers
  = new Dictionary<Answers, List<string>>
  {
    { Answers.Yes, new List<string> { "yes", "y", "yep", "yeah" } },
    { Answers.No, new List<string> { "no", "n", "nope", "nah" } }
  };
```

Thus we can easily define synonyms for each enum value.

And we'll use it by defining this verification method:

```
Answers GetAnswer(string input)
{
  foreach ( Answers item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Answers)) )
    if ( AcceptedAnswers.ContainsKey(item) )
      if ( AcceptedAnswers[item].Contains(input) )
        return item;
  return Answers.Other;
}
```

*Test*

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you agree?");
var answer = GetAnswer(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine($"Your answer is: {answer}.");
```

*Output*

```html
Do you agree?
yep

Your answer is: Yes.
```

*Advanced usage*

```
bool retry;
do
{
  retry = false;
  Console.WriteLine("Do you agree?");
  var answer = GetAnswer(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine($"Your answer is: {answer}.");
  switch ( answer )
  {
    case Answers.Yes:
      // ...
      break;
    case Answers.No:
      // ...
      break;
    default:
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("I don't understand :(");
      Console.WriteLine();
      retry = true;
      break;
  }
}
while ( retry );
```

```html
Do you agree?
I don't know

Your answer is: Other.

I don't understand :(

Do you agree?
yeah

Your answer is: Yes.
```

---

*Please do not use goto more than once per century.*

[How to resolve this compilation error "Using unassigned local variable 'hak'" when using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906189/how-to-resolve-this-compilation-error-using-unassigned-local-variable-hak-wh/65907080#65907080)